# cProfile ignores some builtins

Tags: python-3.x, cprofile

I do not understand why `cProfile` reports the usage of some built-in functions and methods, such as calls to `len()` or `str.count`, but fails to report others such as `list()` or `range()`:

```py
In [1]: import cProfile
In [2]: cProfile.run("for i in range(10): x = list()")
         3 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Is it possible to modify this behaviour so as to obtain a report that includes those calls?